# PHP Array from API get Info from Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have got a call going to API, i am getting the info back like this in an array

if i use:

```
  print_r($balances);
```

this is what will print out

```
  array ( [1CR] => Array ( [available] => 0.00000000 [onOrders] => 0.00000000 [btcValue] => 0.00000000 ) [ABY] => Array ( [available] => 0.00000000 [onOrders] => 0.00000000 [btcValue] => 0.00000000 ) [AC] => Array ( [available] => 0.00000000 [onOrders] => 0.00000000 [btcValue] => 0.00000000 ))
```

now i just want to get the info from only one of these

so let's say i want  [AC]  then with [AC]  i want to get the following info into a varaible

```
available
onOrders
btcValue
```

when i print out the the array like this:

```
print_r($balances[AC]);
```

I get  this like i wanted and returns this:

```
  Array ( [available] => 0.00000000 [onOrders] => 0.00000000 [btcValue] => 0.00000000 )
```

but when i try to get the info from above into a variable like so:

```
foreach($balances[AC] as $key=>$value){ 
    extract($value); 
    echo $onOrders." <br>"; 
}
```

it comes back blank,  but if i use this it works and shows all of the  array coming back from the curl request

```
foreach($balances as $key=>$value){ 
    extract($value); 
    echo $onOrders." <br>"; 
}
```

so what am i doing wrong?  i just want to get ONE of these currencies  not all and i want to be able to use to display in a chart

---

I have included for anyone else stuck somehow the answer and code i used

```
$available=$balances['BTC']['available']; 
$onOrders=$balances['BTC']['onOrders']; 
$btcValue=$balances['BTC']['btcValue']; 

echo  "you have " .$available." BTC Available with " .$onOrders." on Orders, with a BTC Value of  " .$btcValue;
```

Comment: If you open a manual you will see that first argument to `extract` is __array__. In `$balances[AC] as $key=>$value` `$value` is __not__ array. Simple, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, why are you using extract in the first place? Also, i'm not sure if you are missing quotes inside the `[]` like `$balances['AC']`

Comment: using extract to get the info into variables... if i use the whole api result it works but i dont want everyone one of them just One

Comment: why did someone  give me a bad mark?   i made a mistake in coding but gave but showed what i had been trying to do and what did not work...  i showed  work done not just asking for a hand me out...   SMH

Comment: I think you can get the specific onOrders values like $balances['AC']['onOrders']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `extract` simply echo the `value`:

```
foreach($balances['AC'] as $key=>$value){ 
    echo $value." <br>"; 
}
```

EDIT:

```
$ac_var = $balances['AC'];
extract($ac_var);

echo $onOrders." <br>";
```

Comment: or save it into a variable

Comment: Yes...Also can save it in variable as @odedta said

Comment: Ok i do want to save as variable,  but 3 different Variables... so  available
onOrders btcValue, each are diff variables, that is why i was using extract it was closest that i could find

Comment: Just `echo $balances['AC']['onOrders'];`

Comment: OMG  i had that but as ['AC'][2]  and didn't work, so silly of mistake thanks @u_mulder

Comment: thanks @B.Desai  it did work but i used the one liner.  But when i am stuck again i am sure that will some in handy or for someone else too

Answer (score 2):

There are endless options to work with elements of arrays... Some examples:

```
<?php
$data = [
    '1CR' => [
        'available' => 0.00000000,
        'onOrders' => 0.00000000,
        'btcValue' => 0.00000000
    ],
    'ABY' => [
        'available' => 0.00000000,
        'onOrders' => 0.00000000,
        'btcValue' => 0.00000000
    ],
    'AC' => [
        'available' => 0.00000000,
        'onOrders' => 0.00000000,
        'btcValue' => 0.00000000
    ]
];

// tradition and probably best approach
foreach ($data['AC'] as $key=>$value) {
    var_dump($value);
}

// elegant approach that keeps the values out of the calling scope:
array_walk($data['AC'], function ($value, $key) {
    var_dump($value);
});
// a full import, risks collisions
extract($data['AC']);
var_dump($available, $onOrders, $btcValue);

// elegant, fails if elements are in changing order
list($available, $onOrders, $btcValue) = array_values($data['AC']);
var_dump($available, $onOrders, $btcValue);
```

However keep in mind that all attempts to "import" variables into the local scope comes with the risk of naming collisions with already existing variables. That is especially true if you have to rely on external data that might change in structure some day. Usually it is much safer and easier to simply work with the references to the array elements themselves, so `$data['AC']['available']` and so on. If you want to shorten that, then create an explicit reference: `$AC_available = &$data['AC']['available'];`...

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($balances as $cur ) {

    foreach ( $cur as $key => $value ){
        echo $key ." - ".$value;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is a nice addition too, another book   marked bit of code thanks